# Runtime.exec not running but no exception

Tags: java, runtime, exec

I want to use java to run a script in a certain location. The script running fine if I run it manually:

```
     /export/home/trace.sh param1 param2 param3 param4
```

This is my code to run the script from java:

```
     try {

      Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process proc = null;
      System.out.println("starting search");
      proc = runtime.exec( pathServer + "/trace.sh " + fullDate + " " + fullDateTo + " " + mA.substring(2) + " " + mB.substring(2));
      InputStream inputstream           =   proc.getInputStream();
      InputStreamReader inputstreamreader   =   new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
      BufferedReader bufferedreader         =   new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
      System.out.println("end search " + System.currentTimeMillis());
      }
     catch (Exception e)
      {
         System.out.println(e.toString());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

If the script running, it will generate "txt.dat" in a specified location. But there's no "txt.dat" generated. I'm trying to figure out what the exception is, but no exception catch.

Is my code already correct? How do I know if it's processing the script or not? And how can I catch any exception happened during the process? Thanks.

---

**Update 2**

I add some code to print `getInputStream` and `getErrorStream`.
For `getInputStream`, I got nothing, which means it's null.
For `getErrorStream`, I get this as a result

```
         Host key verification failed
```

I still have no idea what this error means.

The java apps is run in server B.

Generally, the script I'm trying to invoke (in server B) will ssh to server A and run other script in server A. It will generate text.dat and then sftp to server B. When run it manually, txt.dat successfully generated and transferred to server B.

---

**Update 3**

Thanks for all help and suggestion. Turns out, my java apps running under different user. When I run it manually, I used another user. So, I have added host key from server B to server A. And it's running successfully now.

Comment: Can you print value of pathServer ?

Comment: did you check the command running manually on console ?? , is it working properly ??

Comment: @Sudhanshu: pathServer is "/export/home". I already verified it.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid: yes. I have run it manually from console and it's running properly.

Comment: you can refer to this :http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wait.php , and using this u can pause your applications running the batch file you come to know whether you bat file is being executed or not , and i would suggest first remove your code from the batch file and give simple make directory comand to check whether your bat file is being executed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug or print the `Process.getErrorStream` and `Process.getInputStream` to check for an error reported by the sub-process.

My guess is that you need to invoke `/bin/sh` as the main program and pass your script as an argument, but I'm not sure. I know that you have to do that on windows.

Comment: Hi Tim, thx for the suggestion. I finally catch the exception using getErrorStream and it said: `Host key verification failed.` Do you know what is this means? The script I run is for generated text and then sftp to other server. It's working fine if I run it manually

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.exec` doesn't throw exception if your command fails.

You get the result of execution using the `process.exitValue()`.

Also you can get your script output reading from the `process.getInputStream()` which you do create in your code but don't read from for some reason. Put some `echo` statements in your script to debug.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few improvements that you can make to your code.

1. Use `ProcessBuilder` to create your process, as opposed to `Runtime`. It provides you more options and greater control
2. Pass each component of your command as a separate string to the builder
3. Fully consume your output and error streams
4. Wait for the process to actually complete

Something like this:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command("/export/home/trace.sh", param1, param2, param3, param4);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    System.out.println("starting search");
    Process proc = builder.start();
    final BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                String line = null;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(2048);
                while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
            } catch (final IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Do something with process output, if needed
        }
    }.start();

    proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("end search " + System.currentTimeMillis());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Perception, thx for the suggestion. I tried running your code but I got this exception `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/export/home/trace.sh 20130401 20130402 62813 62815 ": error=2, No such file or directory`                                             I don't understand why it said no such file or directory, I even running those exact same command and succeed.

Comment: Does the script attempt to create/access a temporary directory? It's possible your Java program is not running with enough privileges, and cannot create the same directory when your invoking the trace program through it.

Comment: No, it's not create/access temporary directory. But the script will ssh to other server. Is this related?  And why the error is different when I use runtime.exec? When I use runtime.exec and catch the exception, it said `host key verification failed`

Comment: hi perception, I already found the problem *updated on first post*. However, I'm still getting same exception if I use ProcessBuilder. But success using runtime.exec.